# Suspension, using Archimedes' principle

Tags: forces

Why, when an object placed in a liquid, even with the same density, does it always float/sink?

The upthrust will equal the weight, right; why doesn't it remain suspended?

Is it due to the random nature of the environment?

Comment: Why do you think that objects immersed in something with the same density don't remain suspended?

Comment: Objects denser than water at the surface will sink to a depth at which their weight equals that of the *volume* of water they displace, then they remain suspended.

Comment: @JMLCarter An object denser than water will sink.  An object less dense will displace it's mass while it floats.  An object more dense will try to displace it's mass; but the pressure of the water is not enough to support it, so instead it sinks and displaces only it's volume.  If the mass it has to displace to stay up is more than the volume of the object, it can not be held up by the water (and that object overall also must be more dense than the water).

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote too.

Answer (score 1):

If an object is simply suspended, then its state of motion does not change and from Newton's first law it follows that there is no net force acting on it. An object in a liquid is suspended only if its density is less than or equal to that of the liquid.

In case of lesser density, the object partially floats outside since it requires lesser volume of water to achieve equilibrium from the upthrust. It is suspended because first of all, net force =0. Secondly, if it goes upwards the gravity dominates and if goes downwards, upthrust dominates. So, it can't move and is suspended.

In case of equal density, the object is completely submerged in the liquid. Under normal conditions, it is suspended just below the surface. Interesting thing about this situation is that you can apply a force and move the body to any point inside the liquid. **It will remain suspended as net force is 0 and the body has no tendency to move**. So yes, it will always remain suspended everywhere in the liquid only when the densities are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The upthrust corresponding to archimede's principle itself describes the reason behind why objects float/sink.

Think over the familiar example of: why the iron ball sinks but iron ship floats?

The floating depends on the force acting at specific area of contact.